# How to do a little math in the criteria_range of Countifs Functions (using OR in Countif)

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, countif

The Excel File is like this

```
A  B
1  0
0  1
1  1
0  1
0  0
1  0
```

I want to use Countifs function to count how many rows have at least one "1" in any columns, like

```
=Countifs(A:A+B:B,">=1")
```

or

```
=Countifs(or(A:A=1,B:B=1))
```

I know I can add a Column C, let **Column C = Column A + B**, and then just count Column C; or I can count the total rows and count rows with "0" in both columns, and then calculate **Total Row - Both "0"**. But in real Scenario, I have more complicated situation, so I prefer not using these two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) to provide cyclic calculation.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A6)+(B1:B6)>=1))
```

[image: sump_cyclci]

SUMPRODUCT does not like trying to calculate text values and full column references slow it down so keep your ranges to a minimum. Using the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) can help isolate a dynamic range of true numbers.

Comment: Thank you! but what does "--" mean?

Comment: tl;dr: it converts text or boolean to a number. Long story: search for [double unary](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/what-does-a-double-unary-operator-in-a-sumproduct/9fee1133-130f-4261-90b8-d32d5b885f9a?auth=1).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A6=1,1,IF(B1:B6=1,1,0)))
```

Being an array formula, you'll have to enter this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together.

[image]

Comment: I'm very curious that why your formula need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, but the other one `=SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A6)+(B1:B6)>=1))` does not need to? They are all array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=COUNT(A:A)-COUNTIFS(A:A,0,B:B,0)` to count both `0` columns and subtract it from the total rows:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Or you can use:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,1)+COUNTIFS(A:A,0,B:B,1)+COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,0)
```

if it is not clear what it the total number of rows.